# Redirect user if URL contains a specific keyword with htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, url, http-status-code-404

I need help with setting up a rule inside `.htaccess` that does the following:

Whenever the requested URL contains keyword `love` then redirect the user to another URL or maybe show a 404 page.

Clarifying a bit more: If someone tries to access this URL --> `www.example.com/love` or `www.example.com/?love` or any URL that contains the word love should be redirected to a 404 page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to deal with matching something in the path and matching something in the query string separately, since Apache does not provide a variable containing both. The first [RewriteRule](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) here matches "love" in the path, and the second rule limited by the [RewriteCond](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) matches "love" in the query string.

```
RewriteRule .*love.* - [R=404]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .*love.*
RewriteRule .* - [R=404]
```

Comment: The regex `.*love.*` is the same as simply `love`.

Answer (score 0):

> Whenever the requested URL contains keyword "love"

If you want to exclude words that contain these letters as a sub-word. eg. "glove", "slovenly", "cloves", etc. then you need to incorporate word boundaries in the regex, eg. `\blove\b`.

You can also do this with a single rule by checking against `THE_REQUEST` server variable, which contains both the URL-path and query string.

For example:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \blove\b
RewriteRule ^ - [R=404]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
RewriteRule ^(.+?)www.domain.com.*\.love/.*$ - [R=404]
```

Comment: This will never match since the `RewriteRule` _pattern_ matches the URL-path only, not the hostname. However, the dot is escaped to match a literal dot and you've introduced a slash that isn't present in the example URL in the question.